# Sort a spreadsheet by one column while keeping the contents of every 4 rows together?

Tags: microsoft-excel

The last column is a total of the second-to-last column. I want to sort by the last column in units of 4 rows. That is, each pack of four rows should be considered one item and should not be broken up.

[image]

Comment: How do I group them into the packs of 4? Its a large sheet. Too much to do manualy

Comment: Are the values in column A unique? If so you could perhaps set up a couple of helper columns to sort which would be a concatenation of H + A.

Comment: Yes column A is unique. How do i set up helper columns?

Answer (score 0):

Short of someone having a better way to sort you could do the following.

You will need two sort columns, the first to sort your totals column "H" and the second for your identifier column "A". So that you can sort you need to populate the missing data.

For column "I" the formula is in the below pic and for column "J" it's essentially the same except your changing column "H" for "A" in the formula. All this is doing is automating the task of filling in the blanks.

=IF((H2=""),I1,H2)

[image]

Once all your data is in the two sort columns it would probably be best to copy and past to values the two support columns to remove formulas, then you can do a normal sort using "Sort Col 1" and then adding a level for "Sort Col 2) This only works with column "A" being unique.

[image]